# Why does poll require its main parameter to live beyond the call?

Tags: c, posix, inotify

I’m exploring poll() function on a small project of mine, and I noticed that this snippet crashed:

```
ErrorCode XNotifier_Linux::updatePoll()
{
    ErrorCode ret = Success;

    struct pollfd descriptors = { m_fd, IN_MODIFY, 0 };
    const int nbDescriptors = poll(&descriptors, m_fd+1, 10*1000);

    if (descriptors.events & (POLLIN | POLLPRI))
        ret = DataIsPresent;

    return ret;
}
```

Valgrind is quite helpful here, because it points out that the poll field `ufds` in unitialized :

```
==833== Syscall param poll(ufds.fd) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==833==    at 0x569CB28: poll (in /lib64/libc-2.14.1.so)
==833==    by 0x400F7A: xnot::XNotifier_Linux::updatePoll() (linux.cpp:72)
==833==    by 0x400D4B: xnot::XNotifier_Linux::update() (linux.cpp:28)
==833==    by 0x400FF4: main (linux.cpp:90)
==833==  Address 0x7fefffbb8 is on thread 1's stack
```

As `descriptors` was created on the stack, I understand that when the function returns, the pointer to `descriptors` is no longer valid. I thought that this pointer might be used after the function returns. To confirm that, I changed the line declaring descriptors to : `static struct pollfd descriptors = { m_fd, IN_MODIFY, 0 };` and the crash disappeared.

Why should descriptors outlive the call to poll()?
(Or is there something I got wrong?)

P.-S. : the descriptor was filled by inotify `m_fd = inotify_init();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have misidentified the problem.

```
const int nbDescriptors = poll(&descriptors, m_fd+1, 10*1000);
```

This is wrong because the first argument to `poll` is a (pointer to an) array, and the second argument is the number of elements in that array.

As a result, the system call is reading past the end of the array.  By declaring it `static` you just moved things around in memory and got lucky.

You need:

```
const int nbDescriptors = poll(&descriptors, 1, 10*1000);
```

Comment: Oh. that makes plenty of sense, thanks for pointing it out. As the French man page I was reading was confusing about the second argument, I went to see the man of `select` and picked the description from there: "nfds est le numéro du plus grand descripteur de fichier des 3 ensembles, plus 1." 
I will poke the translator so that it updates its page.